# Pivotal tc Server v.3.1 won't start

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-tool-suite, tcserver

I've recently downloaded `STS` and I tried firing up the TC Server, but it gives this error:

> `Server Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.1 failed to start.`
>
> `Error: Could not find or load main class`
>   `Files.Spring.sts-bundle.pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.0.RELEASE.base-instance.conf.logging.properties`
>   `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option`
>   `MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0`

I went to the folder and it seems that the properties file is there.

Is this a bug or is there something wrong with my settings?

Comment: Which version of STS are you running?

Comment: I have Spring Tool Suite 

Version: 3.6.4.RELEASE
Build Id: 201503100339
Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.2)

Comment: I downloaded the STS 3.6.4 version (for mac) and tc Server started without issue. 
`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Jul 07, 2015 4:09:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 5544 ms
Jul 07, 2015 4:09:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1564 ms`

Comment: Maybe try to download and reinstall again.  Also, would be good to tag "spring-tool-suite" for this issue, if it persists.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might have already solved this. But just answering.

You need to make sure that there are no whitespaces in the path of your STS location.

Example : F:\softwares\STS - is the example of location to which you can extract your zip file of STS or install you exe file of STS.

Wrong  : F:\softwares\IDE Softwares\STS - Is illegal. Pivotal is expecting no whitespaces in the location from which it gets the server source i.e., you sts installation location

STS location could be F:\softwares\STS\spring-tool-suite-3.7.0\sts-bundle, so that your server location would be F:\softwares\STS\spring-tool-suite-3.7.0\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE.

Final solution is, there should not be any whitespaces in the path from which STS pics up the server.

Comment: You better should write spaces as whitespaces . Thanks it saves a lot time!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Apparently there is a bug with too long path to that file (logging.properties) and I solved it by shortening the path to the 
... /conf/logging.properties file
I simply moved that file to c:/dev and changed the path in launch configuration 
(double click server name in the "servers" tab and click on "open launch configuration" -> click "Arguments" -> edit path in the "VM arguments" section)
OR
you can move the whole STS folder into folder that has shorter name.