# Pivotal tc Server failed to start in Spring tool Suite

Tags: tcserver

I have a problem setting up the environment in my Spring tool Suite. It's as simple as not being able to start the server successfully. Because whenever I start it, it returns this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   Workspace.sts-bundle.pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE.base-instance.conf.logging.properties

I am using the 3.7.0 release of STS. What could be the possible reason for this? Any suggestions?

Comment: I would delete the server & re create.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as here: [Pivotal tc Server v.3.1 won't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764940/pivotal-tc-server-v-3-1-wont-start)

Make sure there are no spaces in your path to STS and let us know if that resolves your issue.

Thanks.